# How to move 12 digit numbers from richtextbox to textbox2

Tags: c#, regex

I want to move 12 digit numbers from `richtextbox` to `textbox2` by a program.

I enter these words for `richtextbox`

```
sdgsjglksdjgkl,512025151988,512025151988,512025151988,512025151988,512025151988,sdgsgd
```

I need to get only these 12 digit numbers to  textbox2..

I tried this code but it types `System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection` not these digits

Here i use code for that

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Regex RX = new Regex("[0-9]{1,12}$");
    textBox2.Text = (RX.Matches(richTextBox1.Text)).ToString();
}
```

I don't know how to move these numebrs to the textbox2.. Please help me [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/210dJ.jpg)

Comment: perhaps you should use `string.Split()` method since it's easier to understand if you are not familiar with Regex

Comment: I want only 12 digit numbers... richtextbox has some letters like sgsgsgadgtsg

Comment: Actually in real richtextbox has more than 100000+ character.. I typed little words with 12 digit numbers.....  so i cannot use Split()

Comment: @ImashiEkanayaka What's your desired result? `512025151988` or `512025151988,512025151988,512025151988,512025151988,512025151988`?

Comment: `textBox2.Text = string.Join(",", richTextBox1.Text.Split(',').Where(m=>m.Length==12 && m.All(char.IsDigit))))`

Comment: @ s.akbar -- my desired numebrs are 512025151988 512025151988 512025151988 512025151988 51202515‌​1988

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split with a comma, then take all items that are of length 12 and are all digits:

```
var richTextBox1_Text = "sdgsjglksdjgkl,512025151988,512025151988,512025151988,512025151988,512025151988,sdgsgd";
Console.Write(
        string.Join(",", 
            richTextBox1_Text.Split(',')
                .Where(m=>m.Length==12 && m.All(char.IsDigit))));
# => 512025151988,512025151988,512025151988,512025151988,512025151988
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/EYR5hn)

In your code:

```
textBox2.Text = string.Join(",", 
            richTextBox1.Text.Split(',')
                .Where(m=>m.Length==12 && m.All(char.IsDigit)));
```

For more complex scenarios, use a [`\b\d{12}\b`](https://regex101.com/r/B0n3h0/1) regex like this:

```
textBox2.Text = string.Join("\r\n", 
            Regex.Matches(richTextBox1.Text, @"\b\d{12}\b")
                .Cast<Match>()
                .Select(m => m.Value));
```

Comment: friend. do you know a method to type these numbers without commas and line by line?

Comment: @ImashiEkanayaka `string.Join(",",` => `string.Join("\n",` or `string.Join("\r\n",`

Comment: i want to edit this. it does not extract all ids from below code 
    452239937784,452239937787],"displayName":"GOLDEN"},"2":{"valueName":"GRAY","valueId":2,"hexCode":"#B3B3B3","colorUrl":null,"bgImagePosition":null,"matchingVariationIds":[452239937785,452239937788],"displayName":"GRAY"},"3":{"valueName":"16GB","valueId":3,"hexCode":null,"colorUrl":null,"bgImagePosition":null,"matchingVariationIds":[452239937783,452239937784,452239937785]

Answer (score 0):

1) If you want to return all 12-digit numbers (no more, no less), your regex should be `[0-9]{12}`. The `$` you had in your OP matches the end of a string or line, and the `{1,12}` in your OP matches any number of digits from 1 to 12. If the number has to be surrounded by commas or string anchors so that 13-digit numbers are not matched, your regex would look something like `(?<=^|,)[0-9]{12}(?=,|$)`.

2) If you read this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7sf90t3(v=vs.110).aspx), `Regex.Matches(string)` returns a `MatchCollection`. If you convert that to string, it is just the type name to string. You have to get to each item in the collection, like:

```
Match match = regex.Match(input);
while (match.Success) {
    // Your logic here
   match = match.NextMatch();
}
```

3) I think `string.Split(',')` is easier to use. Then, loop through the array and return all strings that are 12 characters long and are numeric. Alternatively, you could use Linq as others have pointed out.

Comment: was just typing about why the `ToString()` was giving the name of the collection ahah

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use LINQ for this purposes. If you want to get just `512025151988`:

```
textBox2.Text = string.Join("",richTextBox1.Text.SkipWhile(c =>
               !char.IsDigit(c)).TakeWhile(char.IsDigit));
```

Or if you want to get all numbers (`512025151988,512025151988,512025151988,512025151988,512025151988`):

```
textBox2.Text = string.Join(",",richTextBox1.Text.Split(',')
                .Select(d => string.Join("",d
                .SkipWhile(c => !char.IsDigit(c)).TakeWhile(char.IsDigit))))
                .TrimStart(',').TrimEnd(',');
```

Replace first comma with space if you need to join results with space. `string.Join(" ",...`

Answer (score 0):

I have created a method that returns a collection of strings, each containing a number.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> SeparateNumbers(string inputText)
{
    var matches = Regex.Matches(inputText, "[0-9]{12}");

    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
        yield return inputText.Substring(match.Index, match.Length);
    }
}
```

You would simply use it like this. I have also added a way to comma separate them again:

```
string inputText = "sdgsjglksdjgkl,512025151988,512025151988,512025151988,512025151988,512025151988,sdgsgd";
var separatedNumbers = SeparateNumbers(inputText)
    .ToArray();
string numbersOnly = string.Join(',', separatedNumbers);
```

I hope this helps.

**Edit:**

The reason that it gives you this: `System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection` is because of the default implementation of the `ToString` method, it simply gives you the full name of the type (including namespaces).

Also, if you want it to match any amount of numbers up to 12, simply change the regex to `[0-9]{1,12}` as you did initially.